# SmartGWT set Record[] data to a StaticTextItem

Tags: datasource, record, smartgwt, setvalue, listgrid

I have a `StaticTextItem myItem` and I would like to set a List of selected in a `ListGrid myListGrid` items as its value. `myListGrid`'s data is being set via `setData(Record[])`

For my purpose, I know I can do `myItem.setValueField(xxx)` but I also need to do a `myItem.setOptionDataSource(DataSource)`. I think I should set the same data as in `myListGrid`, but I don't know how to convert it from type `Record[]` into a `DataSource` object, so that I can use it.

Can you, please, help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need I think to:

- Instantiate a `DataSource`
- Create its fields with new `DataSourceField` to get the same data structure as your `ListGrid`
- And add the fields created by invoking `setFields()` method
- Set the data origin of your `DataSource` by invoking `setTestData()` method

Hope it could help